# Can you convert a byte array containing non printable characters to a string?

Tags: java

Will the string be created if the byte array contains non-ascii characters?

```
String s  = new String(byte[] b)
```

Comment: Short answer is yes. However it's not at all clear what your real question is. Please note that the ASCII character set does contain some non-printing character codes.

Answer (score 2):

Interpreting individual bytes as ascii characters, it is easy to reject values under 32 and above 126.

```
public static boolean isPrintableAscii(byte value)
{
    return (value > 32 ) && (value < 127);
}

public static String readableText(byte[] buffer, int offset, int bufferSize)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for( int index = 0; index < bufferSize; ++index)
    {
        byte current = buffer[offset+index];
        if( isPrintableAscii(current))
        {
            builder.append((char)current);
        }
        else
        {
            builder.append('.');
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

When encountering a non-printable byte, I just print a '.' used by hex dump utilities for ages.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `new String (byte[] data, String charsetName)` passing second parameter as `US-ASCII`

Comment: It should be noted that this tries to interpret *everything* and so may not behave as desired when given data that encodes both printable characters and raw binary values - the binary values can actually be misinterpreted in ways that end up concealing some of the preceding printable ones.

Answer (score -1):

No, it will not fail. However, there ways to detect non-ascii characters in a string and remove them. But Strings with non-ascii characters are perfectly fine.